# HTML content filtered on blog page

Tags: themes, responsive

On my blog page where my all post are listed all formating is filtered and the post text is in a paragraph tag with all other formatting HTML tags removed. It works fine on the posts single page.

How can I fix it and allow my posts to be visible till "more break" with all formatting.

Comment: You probably need to replace the_excerpt() with the_content(). Have a look at the [codex on the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#the_excerpt.28.29_vs._the_content.28.29).

Comment: Post the relevant code from the template that produces the blog page, please.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin area -> Appearance -> Editor

and open Archive.php template from right side and change the following line from

```
the_excerpt();
```

to

```
the_content();
```

Thanks to @kraftner

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#the_excerpt.28.29_vs._the_content.28.29)